# Get number of text fields with text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uitextfield

I have a view with about 20 textfields, and I want to check the number of fields that have text, not the number that are empty. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Will you please be clear ? i cant understand what you have asked !!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the text fields are inside `theView`:

```
NSUInteger count = 0;
for (UITextField *textField in theView.subviews) {
    if ([textField isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        if ([textField.text length])
            count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but you might want to check the class before you access the text property.